# Set parametric mixin output as variable in LESS

Tags: less

How do i set a parametric mixin output to a variable?

Say i have this custom mixin with these parameters:

```
.gradient(#555, #333, #777);
```

I want this to be put into a variable so i can refer to this specific gradient throughout my code.

Wrapping it like this:

```
@mixin elGradient() {
    @include .gradient(#555, #333, #777);
}
```

for inclusion like this:

```
.element {
    @include elGradient;
}
```

Yields a parse error.

Comment: of course LESS does not support SASS directives. see below.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, pretty unamazing language mixup on my part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.elGradient() {
    .gradient(#555, #333, #777);
}

.element {
    .elGradient();
}
```

This is the simplest way. Alternatively it would make sense to get use of the [extend](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/README.md#extend) feature if you really need to include same properties again and again:

```
.elGradientBase {.gradient(#555, #333, #777)}
.elGradient() {
    &:extend(.elGradientBase all);
}

.element-1 {
    .elGradient();
}

.element-2 {
    .elGradient();
}

// etc.
```